# random 404 errors on existing files

Tags: 404, iis

this may not be due to EE, but my site runs on EE so I want to ask.

We are randomly getting css and js files returning a 404 error.  They exist, and a refresh loads them properly but it's hardly a good user experience to have a page load without CSS 10% of the time.

ex:     nothing special about that being in a template right?  Been using EE for almost 2 years and this just seemed to crop up.

Any ideas on where to look?  I am running EE 2.8.1 on a windows server with IIS

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "nothing special about that being in a template right"? Do you mean your CSS and JS files are stored as EE templates?

Comment: I think I found the problem.  This "cache-busting" rule in IIS seems to have been the problem

<rule name="Cachebusting">
     <match url="^(assets/(css|js)/)(v-\d+\.)((.+).min.(js|css))$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:4}" />
</rule>


when I added a modified datestamp to the file, it works.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/v-<?php echo $css_modified; ?>.community-styles.min.css" />